# Weird behavior when moving or scaling or rotating default cube or any first object

Tags: objects

This just started today. Everything was working fine before. Reinstalled no change. Installed 2.83 beta. No change. Rebooted to Ubuntu no problem there. Any ideas? The material I link to below shows my problem.

https://youtu.be/pEctF8ogKJ4

Comment: Hello :). You're using Blender 2.83 (still in beta), wouldn't blender 2.82 work better?

Comment: Hi. While videos can be good, ideally all question content should be in the question body, in the form of good descriptions of the issue and images. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know the problem. I had this before. Deselect evrything in the edit mode then go back to object mode. To deselect click to an empty place or press <kbd>A</kbd> 2 times fastly.

I don't know what is this problem about but you need to deselect everything in edit mode before going back to object mode.

After I updated my graphics card driver it is not a problem for me anymore.